# Outputting a stored value on the same line with text

Tags: java, variables, output

Need help with this program. I am a very green Java student and am very lost. I want this program to prompt a user to input a number and then have the program decide if it's an odd or even number. I would like the output to display the number and then some text after it on the same line:
e.g.

- User prompted: "Enter integer to check if it is odd or even"
- User enters a "6"
- Program should output "6 is an even number".

This is the program I have so far. It calculates odd/even and outputs text based on result. But every time I try to add something to the `System.out.println("is an even number.")` or the "odd" line it errors out. Not sure how to get the stored variable to output. If the inputted number stored at all?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class OddOrEven
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int integer;

      System.out.println("Enter an integer to check if it is odd or even ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      integer = in.nextInt();

      if ( integer % 2 == 0 )
         System.out.println("is an even number.");
      else
         System.out.println("is an odd number.");
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the errors you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `int` to a `String`, then concatenate it with the `+` operator:

```
System.out.println( Integer.toString(integer) + " is an even number.");
```

Comment: Or the somewhat more readable variant `"" + i + " is an even number"`. The important part is that + works with mixed types as long as you start with a string.

Comment: That line worked! I am not sure why yet but it worked!! Thank you so much. We have not gotten to "concatenate yet. But this sure helps a lot.

Comment: @HerdingDogRescuer `"foo" + "bar"` becomes `"foobar"`.... feel free to accept the answer then...

Comment: @mb21 I was referring to your answer!